# How to escape special characters from a markdown string?

Tags: node.js, encoding, entities

I have a markdown file (utf8) that I am turning into a html file. My current setup is pretty straight forward (pseudo code):

```
var file = read(site.postLocation + '/in.md', 'utf8');
var escaped = marked( file );
write('out.html', escaped);
```

This works great, however I've now run into the issue where there are special characters in the markdown file (such as `é`) that will get messed up when viewed in a browser (`Ã©`).

I've found a couple of npm modules that can convert html entities, however they all convert just about all convertable characters. Including those required by the markdown syntax (for example '#' becomes '&num;' and '.' becomes '&period;' and the markdown parser will fail.

I've tried the libs [entities](https://npmjs.org/package/entities) and [node-iconv](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-iconv).

I imagine this being a pretty standerd problem. How can I only replace all strange letter characters without all the markdown required symbols?

Comment: did you test if browser can open the characters in file correctly(without escaping)

Comment: Have u checked content-type in response header? Some time If content-type is appropriate, then you don't have to encode special(é) character. And also make sure about meta tag(<meta charset="UTF-8" />) in html. To easy debug, just track raw value of character on various state like on before reading, on after converting into html and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by hilarudeens I forgot to include meta charset html tag.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

If you come across similar issues, I would suggest you check that first.